# Unable to access server hosted on VM via https

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I have a server running on ubuntu installed on azure vm. I am able to access the server via http, however when I am trying to connect via https, I am getting error: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I have added inbound rule to allow port 443, but still I am facing the issue.

[image]

Comment: Any update? Is the reply helpful for you?

Comment: Thanks Nancy. It was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

To secure the websites on azure VM, you need to inject the SSL certificate into the VM and configure your web server with a TLS binding. Read this [Tutorial: Secure a web server on a Linux virtual machine in Azure with TLS/SSL certificates stored in Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/tutorial-secure-web-server). Also, you need ensure the port 443 is allowed in the inbound firewall of Azure VM.

When you have done it, you can check if the port 443 is listening on the Azure linux VM via `netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN`, see [How to check if port is in use on Linux or Unix](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-check-if-port-is-in-use-command/)

Let me know if you have any question.